# NPM install throws module not found error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I tried installing node modules by `npm install`
on a new repository but the following error is shown

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module './git-host-info.js'
```

Comment: Is the repo public? If possible, please share the command you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `bin` or `main` points to a missing file in `package.json`?

Comment: its a react app..i dont think there is a ```bin``` or ```main```

Comment: Perhaps `module`? See https://github.com/rpearce/react-medium-image-zoom/blob/master/package.json#L5-L6 for example.

Comment: i just fonund that nm is not working anywhere..wherever i try ```npm install``` it keeps throwing that error